# MATLAB - imagesc() usage

Tags: matlab

I have three functions in spherical coordinates that I want to plot. They are functions of r,theta,phi and I want to view them in the x-y,y-z,x-z planes. I've tried accomplishing this for literally 8 hours. Every method I've tried has been unsuccessful.

How can I accomplish this phenomenally simple task?

```
F1 = (r.^2).*abs((1/(8*sqrt(pi))).*r.*exp(-r/2).*sin(theta).*cos(phi)).^2;
F2 = (r.^2).*abs((1/(8*sqrt(pi))).*r.*exp(-r/2).*sin(theta).*sin(phi)).^2;
F3 = (r.^2).*abs((1/(4*sqrt(2*pi))).*r.*exp(-r/2).*cos(theta)).^2;
```

As you can see, all three of the functions are F(r,theta,phi). That means that there are four dimensions: F,r,theta,phi.

Comment: If you have a function r=f(theta,phi) you can try this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NB6rDT4ycVY)

Comment: eh, i think i dont get this.. - why don't you just put in some r, theta and phi values? .. and then plot(twoPx, twoPy), plot(twoPz, twoPy) and plot(twoPx, twoPz)

Comment: Think of the question this way: I have three functions, each is a function of r,theta,phi. I want two plot all 3 functions F(r,theta,phi). Yes, that's four dimensions.

Comment: @Aabaz, Unfortunately that tutorial is not applicable. I have F(r,theta,phi). Not r=...

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I only realized that you could not isolate one of the variables after taking a close look at your functions, that is when I started looking at the solution I posted below. Thought I would let this link in comment just in case it could be helpful to someone with a closely related problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your functions cannot be expressed as r=f(theta,phi), maybe you can compute the value of f(theta,phi,r) over a grid and then plot an isosurface where your volume data equals your value twoPx.

I tried this small example from which you can expand but I do not know if the shape is correct because I do not know what to expect:

```
n=20;
rmax=5;
twoPx=0;
%%%%%%%%%%
[theta phi r]=ndgrid(linspace(0,2*pi,n),linspace(-pi/2,pi/2,n),linspace(0,rmax,n));
%%%%%%%%%%
value=(r.^2).*abs((1/(8*sqrt(pi))).*r.*exp(-r/2).*sin(theta).*cos(phi)).^2;
%%%%%%%%%%
[x y z]=sph2cart(theta,phi,r);
%%%%%%%%%%
p=patch(isosurface(x,y,z,value,twoPx));
%%%%%%%%%%
set(p,'FaceColor','b','EdgeColor','k','FaceAlpha',0.5);
daspect([1 1 1])
axis square;
grid on;
camlight;
view([0 0]);
```

A little explanation of what this snippet does:

1. define a spherical grid (`ndgrid`)
2. compute the value of your function on that grid
3. compute the cartesian grid corresponding to the spherical grid (`sph2cart`)
4. plot the isosurface where your volume equals twoPx (`patch` and `isosurface`)

Finally you may want to use the Matlab function `view` to specify which plane you want to look from.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, when I run this code in MATLAB I don't see a plot at all. It displays an empty 3D grid.

Comment: You mean that running this exact (same parameters) code snippet you do not see anything plotted ?! I use Matlab R2008b and this displays what looks like a hand-held fan. Again I do not know what results to expect from your functions so modifying the parameters (especially twoPx) could cause the plot to be empty but it should at least display something when run like this.

Comment: when I execute that exact code I get a blank plot. Do you have extra variables in your MATLAB session that are being plotted?

Comment: No, I tried this in a clean Matlab session and it still works for me.

Comment: I'm running MATLAB R2011a. Just as an FYI, these are Hydrogen's atomic orbitals (2Px,2Py,2Pz). They are probability densities for an electron as a function of r,theta,phi.

Comment: If it helps, it works for me too and I see what Aabaz described. nick_name, try debugging by stepping through the code.